# Ajax not replacing with new text when including GET/POST variables

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am following a tutorial on how Ajax works and I have the code setup exactly like mmtuts, but it's not showing the new value until I edit my test.js to this:

This does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        $("#test").load("data.txt", {Firstname: "Test", Lastname: "TestLast"}, function() {
            alert("Hi there!");
        });
    });
});
```

But when I replace with this, it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        $("#test").load("data.txt", function() {
            alert("Hi there!");
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax Tutorial</title>
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="test.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test">
    <p>This is the first content!</p>
</div>
<button id="btn">Click to change</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Just in case someone needs the data.txt:

```
<p>This is the new data!</p>
```

Why won't the first code work? I am passing a string to a text file simply for the tutorial to show the things you can include in the code.

Comment: You want working code or you want to know how it works

Comment: Why are you passing a query string to a URL that appears to represent a **static** text file?

Comment: Its just for the tutorial to show an example on how you can pass it.

Comment: I want working code, but i would love an explanation why mine isn't working since i am learning Ajax and have no background knowledge. I only know HTML and PHP

Comment: "This does not work" — Define "does not work". Look at the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. Are there any error messages? Look at the Network tab. Do you see the HTTP request to the URL? Does it go to the URL you expect? Do you get the response you expect? If not, what is different?

Comment: I get the popup box. But the text doesn't replace to the new text until I delete the query string.

Comment: Look at the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. Are there any error messages? Look at the Network tab. Do you see the HTTP request to the URL? Does it go to the URL you expect? Do you get the response you expect? If not, what is different?

Comment: Possibly, the problem is just that your server doesn't like query strings on static text files.

Comment: You should check what file does it post to, because jQuery's [load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) uses GET and therefor you might be redirected to some other page. So go to Network tab and check what file the script posts to at the end - if there is no text, than nothing will be inserted.

Comment: @skobaljic - My Network tab is saying when i click the button to change the text it has a 405 error and its sending to the data.txt file as POST.

Comment: That means POST method is not allowed on your server for plain text files, [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405). That also means your code will work with many other page types, such as PHP, HTML....

Comment: I changed my data.txt to data.html and it still doesn't work.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, it is about your server configuration. Try uploading your code on some external server.

Comment: In order to work you need to change to some server side language file like php,.net

Comment: It worked when i changed data.txt to data.php. POST can only be recieved via PHP file not an html file. HTML can get GET data tho right? How would i send this array as GET?

Comment: To send it via GET you cannot use plain JS objects, use query string instead. **The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.**

Comment: I understand the concept now! But how could I send it as a GET if I ever needed to?

Comment: use $.get for a straightforward GET, or $.ajax instead of $.load for a bit more control of your request

Comment: What do you mean by query string? Can you provide an example and please answer the question so i can mark it correct for anyone else who may have this issue.

Comment: Firstname=Test&Lastname=TestLast

Comment: the querystring of a URL is the bit after the main url e.g. `https://www.example.com/somewhere?a=1&b=2` the query string is `?a=1&b=2` - it contains variables being passed to the server. The variable named "a" has a value of 1, the variable named "b" has a value of 2. This is as opposed to any variables sent in the request body (but GET requests don't have a body). If you're unsure about such basics, I suggest you study the anatomy of a HTTP request so you understand the underlying technology you're working with. Then it will be much easier to know how to write your AJAX code.

Comment: You can also use jQuery [.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) method to convert objects to query strings...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This code is working fine Please check**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax Tutorial</title>
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn").click(function() {
            $("#test").load("test.txt", function() {
                alert("Hi there!");
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test">
    <p>This is the first content!</p>
</div>
<button id="btn">Click to change</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**i have created on file test.txt and inside that i write something and its working 
Please check and let me know is that you want.**

Comment: Try replacing the jquery with the first block of jquery I posted, with the query string. That is when the issue is occurring and the text isn't being replaced. The popup box opens and alerts me but no text is replaced when you include the query string as the second value.

Comment: @JarrodEstepp it will not work because first you have to post the data and second you have to get the posted data and to get posted data to have to use some server side language like php to get post data